# Converting PDF to 2up with PyPDF2

Tags: python, pypdf

I'm trying to convert a series of pdf files to **2up** so they can be read like a magazine.

I've seen the [pdfjam scripts](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic-research/firth/software/pdfjam/#download), which seem quite complex to install on Mac, so I tried using `PyPDF2`. I thought I could use the `setPageLayout('/TwoPageRight')` method on a  `PdfFileMerger` object, then merge the input file.
But this doesn't change the output format at all.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?
Is there a better way?

Comment: I found a solution, based on the sample script at https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/blob/master/Sample_Code/2-up.py

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment, I found a solution at https://github.com/py-pdf/cpdf/blob/main/cpdf/up2.py

```py
reader = PdfReader("example.pdf")
writer = PdfWriter()
for i in range(0, len(reader.pages) - 1, 2):
    lhs = reader.pages[i]
    rhs = reader.pages[i + 1]
    lhs.mergeTranslatedPage(rhs, float(lhs.mediabox.right), 0, True)
    writer.add_page(lhs)


with open("2-up.pdf", "wb") as fp:
    writer.write(fp)
```